# Ampersand breaks my XML from loading with jQuery

Tags: jquery, xml, ajax

I have descriptions being displayed within an XML document and then loading it into an application with jQuery.

When I try to use '&' it breaks the code from loading. I've also tried

```
&#38;
```

and it doesn't work either.

Is there a work around that will let me contain '&' symbols within my XML?

*edit: Structure is...*

```
<picture title="Name" description="A picture of Adam & Eve"></picture>
```

Comment: Have you tried `&amp;`? It should be legal as of the XML 1.0 spec (one of very few that are)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `&amp;`. The xml parser treats `&` as the start of a [character entity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references)...and `&` by itself is not a valid character entity.

```
<picture title="Name" description="A picture of Adam &amp; Eve"></picture>
```

Answer (score 4):

try wrapping it in a !<[CDATA tag.  Ampersands aren't allowed by parser in xml.

For example:

```
<title><![CDATA[Adam & Eve]]></title>
```

Read more [here](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_cdata.asp)

Comment: So for Adam & Eve you would do "Adam !<[CDATA&]]> Eve" ?

Comment: no you would put it at the beginning of the tag.  see my example.